# Magento2 Add Stored Cards functionality in My Account area

Tags: magento2

My magnto2 account had option to store and list credit card details of a user. In the my account area, there is option to list all the stored cards details which I had added in the checkout area for placing my orders. Anybody please help me to create a form in the my account area to save new stored cards when I'm clicking ***Add new Card***.

The customer is able to enter the details of a valid credit card in the form and save it. The following are the details that needs be captured.

1. Credit Card Number
2. Expiry Date
3. CVV

I'm using brain tree payment method.

Answer (score 0):

hey Magento2 doesn't support saving CC information. you can save the cards on third party secure servers & use for all future Purchases.There are extension available on marketplace for this